# Automate SVN Adds Using NAnt

Tags: svn, build-automation, nant

I want to automate SVN adds using NAnt. I want to add to SVN all new files in a given directory. The NAnt script will successfully execute the add command, however it displays the Tortoise SVN add dialog and this is not acceptable because it will execute on a build server running CruiseControl. The build server is running Windows Server 2003.

Any ideas?

```
<target name="addtest">
    <exec program="c:\program files\tortoisesvn\bin\tortoiseproc.exe" 
        commandline="/command:add * --force /path:C:\svn\test /notempfile /closeonend:1"
        basedir="C:\svn\test"
        failonerror="false"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the exec task, there is a [svn task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/svn.html) which is provided by the [NAntContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/) set of tasks/tools.

```
<svn command="add" ... />
```

Of course doing this probably requires the command line version of subversion, so doing an exec on svn.exe is probably just as good.

```
<exec program="svn.exe" commandline="add..." />
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use tortoisesvn. Get a [commandline svn client](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/).

Comment: If you just want to add a link to an existing answer, then add a comment.  Your answer is duplicating what was already posted.

Comment: Ben, Sunny posted before you.

Answer (score 1):

don't use tortoise!

just drop to command line svn.

```
c:\>svn add ...
```